# Correct OOP Structure for a Dominion AI Player

Tags: c#, oop, artificial-intelligence

I've been tinkering around trying to make an AI player for the popular card game, Dominion (http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/36218/dominion).

If you are not familiar with the game, it is basically a very streamlined cousin of Magic: The Gathering, where there is a large-ish library of cards with different rules on them. Over the course of a game, players buy these cards and incorporate them into their deck.

I am interested in this game from a machine learning perspective - I want to pit bots against each other, have them play millions of games, and try to datamine insights that will make them play better.

I am unsure how to separate the rules of the game (the verbatim instructions printed on each card) from the core AI decision-making logic.

The obvious path that I have started down is creating a class for each Card, and putting both rules and AI stuff in the same place. This is sort of gross - but it seems like the path of least resistance. But maybe it is best for each card to support some sort of interface and then have AI components code against these?

Is there a "Correct" OOP design for this? Or several reasonable possibilities?

Comment: When you say "...is creating a class for each Card, and...", do you mean a class Card with multiple instances or literally multiple classes, one for each card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would lean toward encapsulating the behaviour of a card as its own class, allowing easily for cards that have multiple behaviours (i.e. choices). It would also allow you to write parameterizable behaviours and mix and match them with cards.

So cards would contain things like the cost of the card, when it can be played, its name, etc. It would also contain a list of behaviours that the card can do.

The behaviours are seen by the AI actors as part of the cards. Just another property the cards have that can be weighed along with the cost.

The AI actor that is actually *using* the card's behaviour needs to be able to interpret the behaviours, so the behaviour class might need to contain some hints for the AI to understand it, but no actual AI logic itself should be contained there. If AIs need specific behaviours for specific cards, write that kind of thing into the AI actor, not the card behaviour.

If an AI actor needs to know that, for example, this behaviour has an expected victory point payoff of .2 points/round, that might be a part of the behaviour that acts as a hint to the AI when choosing what cards to buy/play.

But really I don't know how you're approaching your AI actor design so maybe this doesn't make sense. But I think that thinking of behaviour as a property of cards rather than a fundamental part of the cards themselves might help.

It gives you the advantage of encapsulating the AI actors' default actions (things the actors can do without needing cards) as behaviours as well, so you can weigh those actions against card actions without any special-case code.

Answer (score 4):

there are several "correct" OOP designs for this, depending on *how you want to model the game process and the game-playing-agent's AI*

personally, i would take the minimum number of cards for a valid *round* in the game and implement those as instances of a Card class, and implement the players as instances of an Agent class, and implement a few simple playing strategies as instances of a Strategy (pattern) class, and then *see what happens*

run through some tests, have a totally random player as a foil, look at short-term gain/loss max/min operators, try mutating the agent's strategies using a genetic algorithm, download an XCS classifier and see if it is useful to derive strategies...

...the notion of a correct model depends strongly on how it will be used. Once you understand how you need to use the elements of the game and model/manipulate the player strategies/tactics, then you'll know what the 'correct' structure is for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with all the variations of cards in Dominion, but the idea of writing a class for each one seems burdensome. Ideally, you would want to create a general card class that encapsulated all the variations of  instructions on the card, and then load the particular values for a given card into that general class.

I can imagine a class that contains sets of powers and restrictions could be a good general representation. Something like:

- Required in play resources for play
- State where play is prohibited
- Damage types/value
- Health/mana changes
- Effects on other cards (perhaps a dictionary of card ids and effects)
- etc...

Comment: Dominion has a lot of cards, and many have custom actions on them.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Indeed. It's definitely correct to encapsulate the behaviour of each card type in a class. Whether the behaviour should be in extensions of the Card class or in extensions of CardBehaviour classes that are owned by Card instances or by some other method is another question.

Comment: Those actions can not be generalized in any way?

Comment: @jball: Having played the game only once before, I can say that the cards have many different effects. It doesn't strike me as something easy to parameterize.

Comment: The only generalization I have done so far is with the Treasure and Victory point cards.

Comment: @Welbog, I can see the need to have a few different card classes if they truly do have effects that can not be quantified under a single data structure, but I still think that creating a class for each card is madness.

Comment: @jball: They vary wildly.  One may say "look through your discard pile and put any number of Copper cards into your hand." Another may say "Each other player discards two cards or takes a Curse card." (these are paraphrases, btw).  Each one is unique.

Comment: @jball: There are really 7 major types of cards: Treasure, Victory, Action, Reaction, Attack, and Curse.  Cards may be multiple types.  At present, Attack and Reaction cards are also Action cards.

Comment: @jball: Also note that for any given game of Dominion, there are only a few different card *types* and ten instances of each of those types. It makes sense for each card *type* to be a class.

Comment: There are a few things that are generalizable, like *when* a card can be played and *how much* the card costs. But the *behaviour* of each card type is what is wildly different, and behaviour is very hard to parameterize.

Comment: @Welbog: In a standard game, it's (the same) 7 or 9 (Prosperity expansion) Base card types and 10 Kingdom card types, of which there are 10 each for actions and treasure cards and 12 for victory cards.  The Kingdom cards vary between games.

Comment: Don't all the effects fall into the realm of `some predicate(s) -> some affect(s) on some target(s)`?

Comment: I guess my point is, if you can define a reasonably small set of predicate types, affect types and quantifiers, and target types, it could all boil down to one class with different effects for each card.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about the logic for a non-AI version of Dominion, and it's still a mess to figure out.

You almost have to have a class for each card deck and an interface for each card type, keeping in mind that cards may have multiple types (such as Great Hall which is both Action and Victory).

At present, all Attack cards are also Actions, so you may want to make the Attack interface subclass action.  For most cards, the Action would just call the Attack method.  However, there are a few cards where this would need to be different, such as for Minion where you have a choice whether or not to attack.

Reaction cards are also Actions, but will also need special handling, as they can be revealed during an opponent's turn in response to an Attack card.  As of Prosperity, they can also be revealed in response to things other than attacks... Watchtower can be revealed any time you would gain a card.

Duration cards (which I missed in my list of 7 card types earlier) are Actions that stay in play for an extra turn... and also count for the Peddler's buy cost in Prosperity.

Edit: Whoops, I didn't address the AI issue at all here... probably because my own development had been aimed more at a multiplayer network version.

Comment: How did you fare in your implementation? I'm just starting out making my own, is your code available somewhere?

Comment: @AndreasKnudsen: Sadly, it's been on hold for a while now.  One of these days I'll get the motivation to go back and finish it.